# python multiprocessing: sharing bitarray (bitarray 0.8.1)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bitarray

I want to share a 3 gb bitarray (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.8.1) between threads created by multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

I only want to read the bitarray without modifying it. Is the following python 2.7 code really ok? Somehow, it seems to work without using the ctypes (docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import bitarray
import time
def f(x):
    n = 0
    #print shared_arr[n:(10+n)] & shared_arr[n:(10+n)]
    print "worker %d started at time %s" % (x, str(time.time()-start_time))
    print "running %d. bit %d of shared array is: " % (x, x) +str(shared_arr[n:(10+n)])
    time.sleep(2)
    print "ending %d at time %s" %(x, str(time.time()-start_time))
    return x*x

def main():
    print "The number of cpu is %d" % (mp.cpu_count())
    num_cpu_core = mp.cpu_count()
    n = 0
    global shared_arr
    global start_time
    start_time = time.time()
    shared_arr = bitarray.bitarray(18)
    shared_arr[:] = 0
    shared_arr[(n+5):(n+7)] = 1
    a = 10
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = num_cpu_core) # not saving one for the master process
    pool.map_async(f, range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

main()
```

Comment: Multiprocessing doesn't create threads, it creates *processes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on a POSIX system using `fork` semantics for `multiprocessing`, but not on a Windows system that uses `spawn` semantics. `fork` semantics map the same memory into parent and child (copy-on-write, so if it's changed in one, the data stays the same in the other); `spawn` semantics launches fresh Python processes.

Also, side-note, on Windows, I think you want an import guard to avoid a "fork bomb" like scenario, don't invoke `main` at module level unconditionally, but protect it with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so when the spawned child imports the main module as "not main", it doesn't try to reinvoke your `main` function.

Answer (score -1):

Your script isn't importable.

replace the last line:

```
main()
```

with the following two lines:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.